# How to shorten multiple if else with increasing counters

Tags: javascript

I have been finding how to shorten multiple if else with counters but couldn't find anything that is related to my situation.

Currently I have too many if statements for each increasing counter.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Below is my code :

```
$(".gift").each(function(){

        var i = 1;

        $(this).on("click", function(){

            if(i===1){
                TweenMax.fromTo(this, 1, {x:-1}, {x:1, ease:RoughEase.ease.config({strength:8, points:5, template:Linear.easeNone, randomize:false}) , clearProps:"x"})
            }

            if(i===2){
                TweenMax.fromTo(this, 0.9, {x:-1}, {x:1, ease:RoughEase.ease.config({strength:8, points:5, template:Linear.easeNone, randomize:false}) , clearProps:"x"})
            }

            if(i===3){
                TweenMax.fromTo(this, 2/i, {x:-1}, {x:1, ease:RoughEase.ease.config({strength:8, points:5, template:Linear.easeNone, randomize:false}) , clearProps:"x"})
            }

            if(i===4){
                TweenMax.fromTo(this, 2/i, {x:-1}, {x:1, ease:RoughEase.ease.config({strength:8, points:5, template:Linear.easeNone, randomize:false}) , clearProps:"x"})
            }

            if(i===5){
                TweenMax.fromTo(this, 2/i, {x:-1}, {x:1, ease:RoughEase.ease.config({strength:8, points:5, template:Linear.easeNone, randomize:false}) , clearProps:"x"})
            }

            if(i===6){
                TweenMax.fromTo(this, 2/i, {x:-1}, {x:1, ease:RoughEase.ease.config({strength:8, points:5, template:Linear.easeNone, randomize:false}) , clearProps:"x"})
            }

            if(i===7){
                TweenMax.fromTo(this, 2/i, {x:-1}, {x:1, ease:RoughEase.ease.config({strength:8, points:5, template:Linear.easeNone, randomize:false}) , clearProps:"x"})
            }

            if(i===8){
                TweenMax.fromTo(this, 2/i, {x:-1}, {x:1, ease:RoughEase.ease.config({strength:8, points:5, template:Linear.easeNone, randomize:false}) , clearProps:"x"})
            }

            if(i===9){
                TweenMax.fromTo(this, 2/i, {x:-1}, {x:1, ease:RoughEase.ease.config({strength:8, points:5, template:Linear.easeNone, randomize:false}) , clearProps:"x"})
            }

            if(i===10){
                $this = $(this);
                TweenMax.fromTo(this, 2/i, {x:-1}, {x:1, ease:RoughEase.ease.config({strength:8, points:5, template:Linear.easeNone, randomize:false}) , clearProps:"x", onComplete:function(){
                    $this.css("top", "500px");

                    $(".gift").each(function(){
                        $(this).off("click");
                    });
                }})

            }

            i++;

            console.log(i);

        });

    });
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Well... from i=3 to i=9 all the same, as i can see, put it in one condition?

Comment: Given that every situation where `i` is `3` or more is exactly the same, why are you not using an [`if`/`else if`/`else`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)  structure? `if (i === 1)  {...} else if (i === 2) {...} else if ( i > 2 ) {...}`?

Comment: Hi sinisake, how do I do that for i=3 to i=9 in 1 line?

Comment: Hi David, because I copied and paste just to try out whether the whole thing work before I code them properly. =x

Comment: @Dr3am3rz, https://jsfiddle.net/1kh4r0xa/1/, maybe like this?

Comment: Hi sinisake, I tried to use forloop before but when I clicked ONCE on the gift, it will run the loop which is not what I want to do.

Comment: OH! Nvm, I got it to work! I used part of your function! if(i>0 && i<10){
    TweenMax.fromTo(this, 1.5/i, {x:-1}, {x:1, ease:RoughEase.ease.config({strength:8, points:5, template:Linear.easeNone, randomize:false}) , clearProps:"x"})
   } Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to "complex" if else statements as suggested in the comments is to use a [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement:

```
$(".gift").each(function(){

        var i = 1;

        $(this).on("click", function(){

            switch(i) {
                case 1:
                    TweenMax.fromTo(this, 1, {x:-1}, {x:1, ease:RoughEase.ease.config({strength:8, points:5, template:Linear.easeNone, randomize:false}) , clearProps:"x"})
                    break;
                case 2:
                    TweenMax.fromTo(this, 0.9, {x:-1}, {x:1, ease:RoughEase.ease.config({strength:8, points:5, template:Linear.easeNone, randomize:false}) , clearProps:"x"})
                    break;
                case 3:
                case 4:
                case 5:
                case 6:
                case 7:
                case 8:
                case 9:
                    TweenMax.fromTo(this, 2/i, {x:-1}, {x:1, ease:RoughEase.ease.config({strength:8, points:5, template:Linear.easeNone, randomize:false}) , clearProps:"x"})
                    break;
                case 10:
                    $this = $(this);
                    TweenMax.fromTo(this, 2/i, {x:-1}, {x:1, ease:RoughEase.ease.config({strength:8, points:5, template:Linear.easeNone, randomize:false}) , clearProps:"x", onComplete:function(){
                        $this.css("top", "500px");

                        $(".gift").each(function(){
                            $(this).off("click");
                        });
                    }})
                    break;


            }

            i++;

            console.log(i);

        });

    });
```

Comment: Thanks Alex! I was thinking about using switch too! But seeing so many examples I still don't know how to use it. =x